# Maps Crashing The Application After Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, maps

i was Displaying the Maps in my Application , but all of Sudden it start Crashing with the iOS 7 after throwing the Exception . Here are the Xcode Logs and let me know if you want to See the Code , Any help will be really Great .

```
2014-01-17 07:41:03.310 InSite[6608:552b] ERROR:Uncaught Exception: *** -[__NSDictionaryM    
removeObjectForKey:]: key cannot be nil
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x041f75e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00be78b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x04281835 -[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:] + 677
3   InSite                              0x001720c5 -[NSURLConnection(GDNET) gdDealloc] + 119
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00bf8692 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 268
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00bf9adf -[NSObject release] + 25
6   Foundation                          0x026e13fb __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 88
7   Foundation                          0x02569a6e -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 119
8   Foundation                          0x025699d6 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
9   Foundation                          0x026e154d -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:] + 76
10  Foundation                          0x02569d2a -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionDisconnectFromConnection] + 84
11  Foundation                          0x02569ccc _NSURLConnectionReleaseClient + 33
12  CFNetwork                           0x02cfcce1 _ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic11setDelegateEPK24CFURLConnectionClient_V1 + 163
13  CFNetwork                           0x02d9664b ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic15invalidateAsyncEP16dispatch_queue_sU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke_2 + 37
14  CFNetwork                           0x02d965fd ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic15invalidateAsyncEP16dispatch_queue_sU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 210
15  CFNetwork                           0x02d93e20 ___ZNK25URLConnectionInstanceData19_withWorkQueueAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 17
16  CFNetwork                           0x02de1170 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke79 + 31
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fb7f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a104b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fe07f _dispatch_queue_drain + 452
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fde7a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fee1f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 83
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039ff137 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
23  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x03e0de72 _pthread_wqthread + 441
24  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x03df5daa start_wqthread + 30
)
2014-01-17 07:41:03.312 InSite[6608:552b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:]: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x041f75e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00be78b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x04281835 -[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:] + 677
3   InSite                              0x001720c5 -[NSURLConnection(GDNET) gdDealloc] + 119
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00bf8692 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 268
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00bf9adf -[NSObject release] + 25
6   Foundation                          0x026e13fb __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 88
7   Foundation                          0x02569a6e -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 119
8   Foundation                          0x025699d6 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
9   Foundation                          0x026e154d -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:] + 76
10  Foundation                          0x02569d2a -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionDisconnectFromConnection] + 84
11  Foundation                          0x02569ccc _NSURLConnectionReleaseClient + 33
12  CFNetwork                           0x02cfcce1 _ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic11setDelegateEPK24CFURLConnectionClient_V1 + 163
13  CFNetwork                           0x02d9664b ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic15invalidateAsyncEP16dispatch_queue_sU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke_2 + 37
14  CFNetwork                           0x02d965fd ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic15invalidateAsyncEP16dispatch_queue_sU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 210
15  CFNetwork                           0x02d93e20 ___ZNK25URLConnectionInstanceData19_withWorkQueueAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 17
16  CFNetwork                           0x02de1170 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke79 + 31
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fb7f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a104b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fe07f _dispatch_queue_drain + 452
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fde7a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039fee1f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 83
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039ff137 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
23  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x03e0de72 _pthread_wqthread + 441
24  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x03df5daa start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: The error and stack trace are quite clear. In your `gdDealloc` method of your `NSURLConnection(GDNET)` category, you are calling `removeObjectForKey:` on a mutable dictionary but you are passing in `nil` for the key. You are not allowed to pass in `nil` for the key, hence the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:]: key cannot be nil'

its saying clearly key can not be nil

your code is craxhing in this method due to

```
[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:]
```

check and solve it